# Docker image naming conventions considering security

Tags: docker

We have a private Docker Registry (Nexus) for our internal Docker images, `https://company-docker-repo:8081`. These images are never published to Docker Hub, they are for internal usage only.

Our images follow the following naming conventions:
`company-docker-repo:8081/company/<repository>:<tag>`.

A malicious person can upload a new (compromised) docker image `company/<repository>:latest` to docker hub and developers which pull `company/<repository>:latest` instead of `company-docker-repo:8081/company/<repository>:<tag>` now get the wrong image.

What can I do to prevent it?

- Is there a reserved `<repository>` partial name to use, eg. "private/" or "internal/" prefix perhaps?
- Are there conventions to follow to prevent this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is registering the user `company` on Docker Hub, such that the `company/` prefix is claimed by us. Even though we have no intention of publishing under that account. Is that the conventional and recommended way?